# How JSP page works with XSL

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt, jakarta-ee, web

I am struggling with JSP and XSL technologies. The following is the code that I saw in other person's project, which is quite confusing. For my understanding, this guy uses the xsl to render jsp like css to html. Is it necessary to write code like that? I thought that XSL is generated to transform XML, instead of doing what CSS does. I hope someone could explain it further to me, that would be a great help. Thanks in advance!

***LoginAction.jsp***

```
 <%@page contentType="application/xml" import="uts.wsd.*" errorPage="error500.jsp"%><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="loginAction.xsl"?>

                            <!-- Implement page styles + elements from .xsl -->

<% 
//get objects from .xml files
String filePath = application.getRealPath("WEB-INF/users.xml"); %>
<jsp:useBean id="usersApp" class="uts.wsd.UsersApplication" scope="application">
    <jsp:setProperty name="usersApp" property="filePath" value="<%=filePath%>"/>
</jsp:useBean>

<page>

<%
//get needed data

String email = request.getParameter("email");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
//User user = null;
%>

<%
//init login method from java class
User user = usersApp.getUsers().login(email, password);

if (user != null) { //login is successful
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
     %> 
<success />

<% 
//if login is not successful
} else { %>
<fail />

<% } %>

</page>
```

How the fail and success tags work in this page? Is it used to match the xsl?

***loginAction.xsl***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="email" select="email" />
    <xsl:variable name="password" select="email" />

    <xsl:template match="page">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                      ......
                </style>
                <title>Logging In...</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <!-- Page layout -->

                <div class="heading">
                    You are not logged in <br />
                    <a href="index.jsp">Index</a> | <a href="register.jsp">Register</a>
                    <br />
                </div>
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="success">
    <br />
    <hr />
        <h1>Login successful.</h1>
        <p>Click <a href="index.jsp">here</a> to search through available articles.</p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fail">
        <hr />
        <h1 class="h1">Email and/or Password incorrect.</h1>
        <p>Click <a href="login.jsp">here</a> to try again.</p>
        <br />
        <p>Click <a href="register.jsp">here</a> to create an account.
        </p>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> this guy uses the xsl to render jsp

I woult put it another way:

The *.jsp* file contains application logic:

- setup beans and variables,
- check whether there is a logged-in user,
- decide which part of HTML code should be rendered.

But this file does not contain any actual HTML code.
Instead it contains the following "markers":

- `<page>` - Here put HTML, HEAD and BODY tags
  and the initial part of the body content, to be rendered
  in both cases (regardless whether there is a logged-in user).
- `<success>` and `<fail>` - Here put the piece of
  HTML code to render in each respective case.
- `</page>` - Here put closing tags of BODY and HTML.

Note that both `<success>` and `<fail>` are within `if ... then ... else ...`
piece of JSP code.

This ensures that either the first or the second piece of HTML code
will be rendered, depending on existence of a current user, but not both.

Partitioning of the page code between *.jsp* and *.xsl* file
is here a method to separate concens and allow that two
IT guys are able to work concurrently:

- the first guy - a JSP programmer - prepares application logic,
- the second guy - an UI specialist - prepares the presentation layer.

This resembles to some extent the MVC paradigm:

- *.jsp* file contains *Model* and *Controller* parts,
- *.xsl* file contains the *View* part.

Using of XSL transformation to transform the JSP file is a way to join
both these parts in one page to be presented to the browser user.

Comment: So the success and fail tag are actually HTML tag,right?Your explanation is quite straightforward, but it brought me another question. The JSP uses javabean to get XML data and then XSL to render this part of code. XSL seems not directly matching the element in XML and display it in JSP. The order like xml->jsp->xsl.

Comment: And  the notation of success and fail is stranger to me, which is not a closing tag.

Comment: `<success/>` and `<fail/>` are markers, defining where to insert respective parts of HTML code. They are not HTML tags, but for XSLT processor they merely show where to put some piece of HTML, by "executing" (applying) respective templates.

Comment: Do you have any material about that.

Comment: There are numerous tutorials concerning XSLT. Search in the web. StackOverflow is also a rich source of examples. If you start searching for some detail concerning XSLT, e.g. using Google, you are very likely to be given a couple of links to StackOverflow posts.